# Invalid parameter for function URLFOR

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

i have a requirement wherein I have a button on my VF page XYZ_VF

1.The button needs to open a create record page of an custom object 
2.Also when the standard create page is displayed,its lookup field should be prepopulated

How can i extend the below code to implement my functionality?

Note:I am using custom controller

below is my code:

```
<apex:commandButton 
    value="Add Killer Checks" 
    action="!URLFOR($Action.DisplayCheck__c.New,$CurrentPage.Name,[CF00N20000009H4jV=$CurrentPage.Parameters.vname,CF00N20000009H4jV_lkid=$CurrentPage.Parameters.id])}" 
    style="float:center"/>
```

I get the below error:

> Invalid parameter for function URLFOR Error is in expression
>   '{!URLFOR($Action.DisplayCheck__c.New,$CurrentPage.Name)}' in
>   component  in page visitaudit_vf

Please help
THanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you've minced the `URLFOR` parameters.

- first param is `$Page`
- second param is `Id`
- third param is `['param'='eters']`
- fourth param is `Boolean`

try this:

```
<apex:commandButton
    value="Add Killer Checks"
    action="{!URLFOR($Action.DisplayCheck__c.New, null, ['CF00N20000009H4jV'=$CurrentPage.Parameters.vname,'CF00N20000009H4jV_lkid'=$CurrentPage.Parameters.id])}"
    style="float:center"
/>
```

Comment: Adding my 2 cents : check out this post by Sam Arjmandi, he has done an awesome job  explaining URLFOR parameters http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2008/12/urlfor-function-finally-explained.html